# when click on button from Android Application my characteristics write not send data to esp32 module

Tags: java, kotlin, github, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable, Observer {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    public static final String Tag="DetailBle";
    boolean MAINSSTATUS;
    boolean SOLARSTATUS;
//    boolean UPSSTATUS;
    private static boolean UPSSTATUS;
    boolean BATTERYFULL;
    String  CHARGING_STATUS,CHARGING_LABEL;
    View view;
    LinearLayout statusLayout;
    int psckecked;
    Alarms alarms;

    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BluetoothGattService> servicesList;
    BleDevice bleDevice;
    BluetoothGattService service;
    List<StringBuilder> builderList;

    // here we define our variable connected to xml file

    LinearLayout solarArrowLoad, solarArrowBattery, gridArrowLoad, gridArrowBattery,batteryArrowLoad;


    TextView solarToloadP,solarToBatteryCur;
            //gridToLoadP,gridToBatteryCu;  ye comment kiye hai
//    todayPS  totalps,solarPower  ye bhi comment kiya hai

    TextView solarCurrent,batteryVolt,batteryCurrent,SRnumber, gridVolt,loadPersent;
    TextView connetionStatus;
    Button upsStatus,upsMode,highCharging,powerSaving;  // btn to txt here error
    ImageView solarPanel,battery,homeLoad,supply;
    //


    //

    int writeFlag;

    ClickDialog clickDialog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_ble);
        ObserverManager.Companion.getInstance().addObserver(this);
        mBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        BleDevice bleDevice1 = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bleDevice"); //BLE class object
//      bleDevice1.getName().toString();


        if (bleDevice1 != null){
            Log.d("","javed"+bleDevice1.getName());
            start(bleDevice1);
        }

        // D4:D4:DA:30:8D:62
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "yaha dikaat hai ky  bhai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    void start(BleDevice bleDevice1){
        bleDevice=bleDevice1;
        Log.d("","oldhai"+bleDevice.getName());


        if (bleDevice!=null){


            if (BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(bleDevice)){
                initView();
                setData();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                //notifyClick();
               write("hello sir"); //1
                Log.d("Tag","msg"+write("i am coder"));
                Log.d("Tag","msg"+write("i am coder"));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                indicate();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                setMTU();


            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device is not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(Tag+"onCreate","Device id not connected");
        }
        setConnectivityStatus();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //start handler as activity become visible
        // startCkeckStatus();
        super.onResume();
    }


    private void setConnectivityStatus() {
        if (getConnectivityStatus()) {
            connetionStatus.setText(getText(R.string.connected));
            Log.d(Tag,"Connected");
        }
        else {
            connetionStatus.setText(R.string.active_disconnected);
            Log.d(Tag,"Disconnected");
        }

    }

    private boolean getConnectivityStatus() {
        return  BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(bleDevice);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bleDevice!=null){
            BleManager.getInstance().disconnect(bleDevice);
            BleManager.getInstance().destroy();}
        stopNotification();
    }

    private void initView() {
        servicesList = new ArrayList<>();
        builderList= new ArrayList<>();

        connetionStatus=findViewById(R.id.connected_status);

        solarToloadP=findViewById(R.id.solar_to_load_power);
        solarToBatteryCur=findViewById(R.id.solar_to_battery_current);
        // 208 and 209 and 214 ,2013.1113,1117,1118,1198,1120 these line will be connected
    //    gridToLoadP=findViewById(R.id.grid_to_load_power);
    //    gridToBatteryCu=findViewById(R.id.grid_to_battery_current);

//        todayPS=findViewById(R.id.today_power_saved);
//        totalPS=findViewById(R.id.total_power_saved);

  //      solarPower=findViewById(R.id.solar_power);
        //  solarCurrent=findViewById(R.id.solar_current);
        SRnumber = findViewById(R.id.serialNO);
        gridVolt =findViewById(R.id.ip_volt);
        loadPersent=findViewById(R.id.load_presentge);
        batteryVolt=findViewById(R.id.battery_volt);
        batteryCurrent=findViewById(R.id.battrery_to_load_power);



        upsStatus=findViewById(R.id.ups_status);
       upsMode=findViewById(R.id.ups_mode);
        highCharging=findViewById(R.id.high_charging);
        powerSaving=findViewById(R.id.power_saving);

        solarPanel=findViewById(R.id.solar_panel);
        supply=findViewById(R.id.supply);
        battery=findViewById(R.id.battery);
        homeLoad=findViewById(R.id.load);

        gridArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.grid_arroweup);
        gridArrowBattery =findViewById(R.id.grid_arrowdown);

        solarArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.solar_arrow_up);
        solarArrowBattery =findViewById(R.id.solar_arrow_mid);
        batteryArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.battery_to_load);

    }

    private void setData() {
        BluetoothGatt gatt = BleManager.getInstance().getBluetoothGatt(bleDevice);
        alarms=new Alarms(MainScreen.this);

        clickDialog = new ClickDialog(MainScreen.this);
        view =getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
            servicesList.add(service);

        }
        service = servicesList.get(2); // 3-1 services chl rhe hai
    //    Log.d("","i am ser"+service);
////        Log.d("","service1"+service.getCharacteristics().get(1));
//        Log.d("","service1"+servicesList.get(1));
//        Log.d("","service0"+servicesList.get(0));
//        Log.d("","service2"+servicesList.get(2));
        characteristicsList.addAll(service.getCharacteristics());

        /* ************************************* Button ******************************************* */
//        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(view -> {
//            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "data is coming",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
//                if (upsStatus.getText() == getString(R.string.ups_on)) {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "data is coming",
//                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    // String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_off) + "%" + "END";
//                    String input = builderList.get(7).toString() + "%" + "OFF"+ "%" + "END";
//                    Log.d("","buton"+ input);
//                    int status = write(input);
//                    if (status == 4)
//                        upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
//
//                    else
//                        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                } else {
//                    //  String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_on) + "%" + "END";
//                    String input = builderList.get(7).toString() + "%" + " ON"+ "%" + "END";
//                    int status = write(input);
//                    Log.d("YourTag", "write method executed. Status: " + status);
//                    if (status == 1)
//                        upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
//                    else
//                        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//
//        });

        // button hai yha p

//        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//
//
//                        if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
//                    if (upsStatus.getText() == getString(R.string.ups_on)) {
//
//                        // String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_off) + "%" + "END";
//                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() ;
//                        Log.d("","input"+input.toString());
//                        Log.d("","upsss"+builderList.get(10).toString());
//                        int status = write(input);
//                        Log.d("","input"+status);
//                        if (status == 1)
//                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
//                        else
//                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    } else {
//                        //  String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_on) + "%" + "END";
//                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + " ON" + "%" + "END";
//                        int status = write(input);
//                        if (status == 1)
//                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
//                        else
//                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                }
//
//            }
//        });

//        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//
//                try {
//                    if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
//                        Log.d("", "Builder list size: " + builderList.size());
//                        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "data is coming",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        Log.d("","mybuil"+builderList.get(1));
//                        if (upsStatus.getText().equals(getString(R.string.ups_on))) {
//                            String input = builderList.get(1).toString();
//                            int status = write(input);
//                            if (status == 1)
//                                upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
//                            else
//                                Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        } else {
//                            String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + " ON" + "%" + "END";
//                            int status = write(input);
//                            if (status == 1)
//                                upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
//                            else
//                                Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }
//                    }
//                } catch (Exception e) {
//                    // Handle exceptions here
//                    e.printStackTrace(); // This line prints the exception's stack trace for debugging
//                    // You can display an error message or handle the exception in a way suitable for your application
//                    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "An error occurred: " + e.getMessage(),
//                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        });

        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
                    if (upsStatus.getText() == getString(R.string.ups_on)) {
                        // String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_off) + "%" + "END";

                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + "OFF" + "%" + "END";
                        Log.d("","upsss"+builderList.subList(1,10));
                        int status = write(input);
                        if (status == 1)
                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //  String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_on) + "%" + "END";
                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + " ON" + "%" + "END";
                        int status = write(input);
                        if (status == 1)
                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

I have an Android app with a user interface containing a button. On button click, I initiate a write operation to a specific BLE characteristic associated with the ESP32 server to transmit data. However, despite the code being implemented to write data to the characteristic, the data isn't successfully transmitted to the ESP32.
The data I received correctly from the server is below.
UPS%12345678%223%012.8%000%223%00.0%04%1%001%13.5%00.0%00.3%00.0%00.4%000.0%000.0%END
Now I have to send this data from the Android App to esp32.
String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + " ON" + "%" + "END";